# C# LengthCalculator error /An object of a type convertible to double is require

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator

This is c# console app.I am new for programming. Can you guys check this for me am i right? and what am i missing??????

It is program description:

•   Length Calculator

•   Allows user to convert,centimetres to feet and inches

•   feet and inches to centimetres

•   User will select one of the conversions or choose to cancel this option.

•    If the user selects a conversion they will enter the appropriate value(s).
    So for feet and inches to centimetres, the user will first enter the number of feet, then the number of inches.
•
    The number of inches may be 0 in case of say 6ft
•   After the result is displayed, ask the user if they wish to do another Length conversion, to which they can reply “Y” or “N” ( or equivalent lower case letters)
    If yes, the program proceeds as above. If no, returns to Main menu

```
        public static double LengthCalculator() {

        double Centimetres = 0.0, Feet = 0.0, Inches = 0.0;
        string AnotherConversion; 
        string LengthCalculatorMenu;
        int LengthCalculatorOption = 0;

        do {
            LengthCalculatorMenu=("\n1) Convert centimetres to feet and inches "
                                + "\n2) Convert feet and inches to centimetres ");
            Console.Write(LengthCalculatorMenu);
            LengthCalculatorOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Centimetres = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (LengthCalculatorOption == 1) {
                Feet = (Centimetres / 2.54) / 12;
                Inches = (Centimetres / 2.54) % (Feet * 12);
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Centimetres that you wish to convert to feet and inches");
                Centimetres = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe equivalent in feet and inches is {0:C} ft {1:C} ins", Feet, Inches);
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();
            } else if (LengthCalculatorOption == 2) {
                Centimetres = ((Feet * 12) + Inches)*2.54;
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Feet");
                Feet = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Inches");
                Inches = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe equivalent in centimetres is {0:C}", Centimetres);
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\a\t Invalid Option!Option Must be 1 or 2");
            }
        } while (AnotherConversion == "y" || AnotherConversion == "Y");
          return;
    } // end Length Calculator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the method `LengthCalculator` is declared as returning a `double` value yet the actual code doesn't actually return anything

```
return;
```

To fix this you either need to make the method `void` or return a `double` value.  My hunch is that you want a `void` returning method here

```
public static void LengthCalculator()
```